# How to solve : $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{n\cdot 2^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{n\cdot 2^{n}}$$

I need to solve the limit problem above. I have no idea about what to do. What do you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $\frac{n!}{2^n} = \frac{n \cdot (n-1) \cdot \dots \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot 2 \cdot 2} = \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{n-1}{2} \cdot \dots \cdot \frac{2}{2} \cdot \frac {1}{2}$. Does that help you?

Comment: The factorial function grows faster than $2^n$. As naslundx is suggesting, with each consecutive $n$, you multiply the factorial by an ever increasing $n$ term, while with $2^n$ you just keep multiplying it by $2$. Soon enough, $n! > 2^n$ will become true. In this specific case, that is true for $n \geq 4$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since
$$n!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot \cdots \cdot n\ge 2\cdot 3\cdot 4^{n-3}$$
$$\frac{n!}{n\cdot 2^n} \ge 2\cdot 3\cdot \frac{4^{n-4}}{2^n}=\frac{2\cdot3}{4^4} 2^n$$

for $n\ge 4$. Therefore the sequence diverges.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n2^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$

and apply the quotient test

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{n2^n}=\frac2n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

and thus the series converges, which means

$$a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\implies\frac1{a_n}=\frac{n!}{n2^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

Comment: Why do you get more than "an does not converge to zero"?

Comment: @Keba, I don't understand your question. Sorry.

Comment: Ah sorry. Misread the last line, got it now :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint :

$$\frac{n!}{n\cdot2^n} = \frac{(n - 1)!}{2^n}\\
= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{(n-1)(n-2)...(3)(2)(1)}{\underbrace{2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot...\cdot2}_{\text{n-1 times}}}\\
= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{n-1}{2}\cdot\frac{n-2}{2}\cdot\dots\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

Hopefully you can see how this is divergent.

Answer (score 3):

Use Stirling's formula $n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n(1+O(\frac{1}{n}))$. You wil get

$\frac{n!}{n2^n}=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\left(\frac{n}{2e}\right)^n(1+O(\frac{1}{n}))\to  \infty$